# asp.net how to code for Namespace in web-forms VB language

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms, namespaces

I have never used Namespace(s) when coding WebForm application using VB language.  Can I pls see a proper example based on this code snippet from one of my files.  I do not know **where** to place the "Namespace spacename" sentence.
Since my code refers to a partial class in a **filename.aspx.vb** file, how is this namespace reference coded/represented in the **filename.aspx** file as the art-work design of the web-page.

```
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Partial Class Reports01
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Private Enum eFORMSTATE As Integer
   ... working VB code with methods and events follows...

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
Namespace XXX

Partial Class Reports01
...
End Class

End Namespace
```

also change aspx file from

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Reports01.aspx.vb" Inherits="Reports01" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Reports01.aspx.vb" Inherits="XXX.Reports01" %>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I ask if I need Namespace(s) if all source-code is within one VS project?  And, when I deploy to web-hosting, do I have to do something with the web.config or any other source code?

Comment: Namspaces are using to organize code and prevent name conflicts. You probably do not need to put web forms into namespace(s).  Every class inside namespace, reuqire specify namespace while make object, like Dim o = XXX.classYYY (). If you want to avoid providing XXX everytime you may make namespace 'default' by using: project settings (References -> imported namespaces), or web.config (system.web -> namespaces) or Import on source files.